# Using a result class with database operations

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

Recently I came across a project where a function to add a row into a Room database was wrapped in a Result class.  I want to know if this is really necessary and why.  When would a database insert method for some unknown reason fail at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When would a database insert method for some unknown reason at run time.

Never.

However, the un-weary could be fooled by a [Trigger](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

Of course it could simply be that the result of the insert is being collected. That is that the Convenience [@Insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Insert) will return the [rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) of the inserted row or -1 if the row could not be inserted (depends upon the conflict handling strategy).